# How to compare two tables in Hive based on counts

Tags: hive

I have below hive tables

```
Table_1
ID
1
1
2

Table_2
ID
1
2
2
```

I am comparing two tables based on count of ID in both tables, I need the output like below

```
ID 
1 - 2records in table 1 and 1 record in Table 2
2 - one record in Table 1 and 2 records in table 2
```

Table_1 is parent table

i am using below query

```
select count(*),ID from Table_1 group by ID;
select count(*),ID from Table_2 group by ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a full outer join on your queries  with the on condition as X.id = Y.id, and then select * from the resultant table checking for nulls on either side.

```
Select id, concat(cnt1, " entries in table 1, ",cnt2, "entries in table 2") from (select * from (select count(*) as cnt1, id from table1 group by id) X full outer join (select count(*) as cnt2, id from table2 group by id)
on X.id=Y.id
)
```

Comment: Can you let me know how i can achieve that in query

Comment: This is not working , i am getting Nulls all the way

Answer (score 0):

Try This. You may use a case statement to check if it should be record / record**s** etc.

```
 SELECT m.id,
       CONCAT (COALESCE(a.ct, 0), ' record in table 1, ', COALESCE(b.ct, 0),
       ' record in table 2')
FROM   (SELECT  id
        FROM   table_1
        UNION
        SELECT id
        FROM   table_2) m
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(*) AS ct,
                         id
                  FROM   table_1
                  GROUP  BY id) a
              ON m.id = a.id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(*) AS ct,
                         id
                  FROM   table_2
                  GROUP  BY id) b
              ON m.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this Python program to do a full comparison of 2 Hive tables:
https://github.com/bolcom/hive_compared_bq

If you want a quick comparison just based on counts, then pass the "--just-count" option (you can also specify the group by column with "--group-by-column").

The script also allows you to visually see all the differences on all rows and all columns if you want a complete validation.